# Is checking for optional characters required in mysql REGEXP?

Tags: mysql

I have a few rows, in a users table with a name column:

```
SELECT name FROM users;
+--------------------+
| name               |
+--------------------+
| Administrator Core |
| Marketing Guy      |
+--------------------+
```

Now I want to check if the name column contains specified strings. For example, I want to check if 'Mark' or 'ket' is present in any row, and if so return it.

Both of these seem to work:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) REGEXP 'ket|Mark'\G;

SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) REGEXP '(.+)?ket(.+)?|(.+)?Mark(.+)?'\G;
```

Does the first one implicitly check for optional characters around ket and Mark? That's not how it would work with many programming languages. That is why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the quite clear examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), I performed a few tests (below).
The tests give 1 for true (i.e. a match) and 0 for false (no match).

Note the use of ^ and $ for the start and end of the REGEXP.

To answer your specific question, your first REGEXP doesn't care about any characters around 'ket' or 'Mark' - it just checks to see if either exists anywhere in the string and returns 1 if there is any match. '^Mark' will search for 'Mark' and 'Market' and any other string beginning with 'Mark'. The same thing happens for the $ for the end of strings.

Check out the examples and try and follow them - Regular expressions are a great string to your SQL bow and it is very worthwhile learning them.

```
mysql> SELECT 'Mark' REGEXP '^Market|.*katerina.*';
+--------------------------------------+
| 'Mark' REGEXP '^Market|.*katerina.*' |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP '^Market|.*katerina.*';
+----------------------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP '^Market|.*katerina.*' |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP 'ket|Mark';
+----------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP 'ket|Mark' |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP 'ket$|Bark';
+-----------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP 'ket$|Bark' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP 'ket|Bark';
+----------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP 'ket|Bark' |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP '^ket|Bark';
+-----------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP '^ket|Bark' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP '^ket$|Bark';
+------------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP '^ket$|Bark' |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LOWER()`, REGEXP is likely to do case folding for you:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP 'market'; -- utf8_general_ci happens to be in effect
+--------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP 'market' |
+--------------------------+
|                        1 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'Market' REGEXP 'market' COLLATE utf8_bin;  -- _bin means no case folding
+-------------------------------------------+
| 'Market' REGEXP 'market' COLLATE utf8_bin |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         0 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

As for your question about surrounding stuff:

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc Market xyz' REGEXP '^market$';
+------------------------------------+
| 'abc Market xyz' REGEXP '^market$' |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  0 | -- anchored, so fails
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'abc Market xyz' REGEXP 'market';
+----------------------------------+
| 'abc Market xyz' REGEXP 'market' |
+----------------------------------+
|                                1 | -- unanchored, so succeeds
+----------------------------------+
```

Perl's `=~` and PHP `preg_match` work the same way (in these examples).